# C++ vector<string> segfaults

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I keep getting segfaults on following code! Can anyone explain what is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line, '\n');
    istringstream iss(line);
    vector<string> result;

    for(string token; getline(iss, token, ' '); )
    {
        //if(token.empty()) continue;
        result.push_back(token); // << Segfaults here
    }

    for(int i = result.size()-1; i>=0; i++)
    {
        cout << result[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  for(int i = result.size()-1; i>=0; i++){
```

Your loop doesn't stop.

Perhaps you want:

```
for(int i = result.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Or, better yet:

```
for(auto i = result.rbegin(); i!= rend(); i++) {
  cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: damn! Why didn't I see this! Thanks!

Comment: You probably didn't see it because you didn't add logging to troubleshoot. The most obvious thing to log would be `i` and `result.size()` right before the `cout` line. That would have given the problem away immediately. (You can do the same thing with a debugger, by analyzing the core dump, or many other ways.)

Comment: Another thing: Should `auto i = result.rend(); i!=result.rbegin(); i--` also work fine? `auto` does not seem to work. What should I include for it to work?

Comment: @cipher Yes, but that will go forwards. I think you want to go backwards, no? If you decrement a reverse iterator, it goes forwards in the sequence.

Comment: @cipher: `auto` requires C++11 or later. If you're stuck in the past, you need `vector<string>::reverse_iterator` instead. Starting from `rend()` would be wrong - that's a "past-the-end" iterator used to mark the end of the reversed sequence.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, he'd need `i = result.rend()-1; ...` Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider to use `boost::adaptors::reverse`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x {1,2,3};
    for (const auto& i : boost::adaptors::reverse(x))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in an answer before, you have a problem with the index check `i>=0` here:

> ```
> for(int i = result.size()-1; i>=0; i++)
> ```

However, I'd like to point out that you can raise the *"semantic level"* of your code (and avoid bugs like the one above), using **reverse iterators**, e.g.:

```
 for (auto it = result.rbegin(); it != result.rend(); ++it)
```

Note that with code like this you make it clear to the code reader/maintainer that your intent is to traverse the vector in *reverse* order (using **`rbegin()`** and **`rend()`**).

---

Compilable **sample code** follows ([**live here**](http://ideone.com/TfZkl4)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> result{ "Hello", "World", "123" };

    for (auto it = result.rbegin(); it != result.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 123 World Hello
> ```